# Woocommerce attempt to exclude USPS for flammable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, usps

New to WP from ASP.NET side of the house. Using WP 3.8.1 with USPS and FEDEX extentions from woocommerce I am attempting to exclude all but FEDEX Ground rates from appearing on the checkout page for products that are flammable and can not be shipped via air. I have written a function and placed it in my themes functions.php file. I does not work. Maybe I am using wrong tag in add_filter.

Figured this one out. So I have edited my original code for those who need it.

The product IDs are hard-coded and that needs further dev. The available methods string was difficult until I figured that I needed to do a print_r to expose them. Uncomment that line to expose them. They are particular to the woocommerce USPS and FEDEX extensions and maybe not documented.

```
    // Hide USPS shipping methods when flammable items in cart 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'hide_usps_when_flammable_in_cart' , 1 );

    /** Hide usps shipping when flammable items in cart
        @param array $available_methods 
    */ 
    function hide_usps_when_flammable_in_cart( $available_methods ) {
         // printing the methods so I know the available methods to exclude
         // echo "<pre>" . print_r( $available_methods, true ) . "</pre>";
        global $woocommerce;
         // Get all products in cart
        $products = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        //store product id's in array
        $volitile = array(170,191,192,194,196,199,201,204,206,208,209,210,212,214,217,262);

        // loop through the items looking for one in the ineligible array
        foreach ( $products as $key => $item ) {
            if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $volitile ) ) {
                unset($available_methods['usps:flat_rate_box_priority']);
                unset($available_methods['usps:flat_rate_box_express']);
                unset($available_methods['usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL']);
                unset($available_methods['usps:D_STANDARD_POST']);
                unset($available_methods['fedex:FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER']);
                unset($available_methods['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY_AM']);
                unset($available_methods['fedex:FIRST_OVERNIGHT']);
                unset($available_methods['fedex:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT']);
                unset($available_methods['fedex:FEDEX_2_DAY']);
                unset($available_methods['fedex:STANDARD_OVERNIGHT']);
                break;
            }
        }

        return $available_methods;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to hard-code the list of flammable items? Shouldn't this be a property of the respective products?

Comment: Yes, hard-coding is always a last ditch resort and I am interested in the deadline any way I can at first. The question is how. If you have a better solution then please let me know.

Comment: I do not know this woocomerce thing, so I do not know how easy/difficult it is to add another property to all items.